# Calculate $\gcd(c^a+1,c^b+1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

Given positive integers $a$, $b$ and $c$, I'd like to ask whether we may adopt some variant of the Euclidean algorithm to calculate $\gcd(c^a+1,c^b+1)$ fast?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my exercise, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context: What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc. Something to both show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for further guidance.

Comment: Start from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/533769/11619).

Comment: Use of [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cgcd(a%5Em%2B1%2Ca%5En%2B1)%24&p=1) is highly recommended when you suspect that the question has already been asked and answered.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I didn't know about Approach0.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I think this post probably solves the problem, but I'd like to ask what the function $v_2$ is?

Comment: I find that $v_2(n)$ is the 2-adic order of $2n$.